# How to get class level annotation from ProceedingJoinPoint

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to implement an interceptor with @Aspect. I need to get class level annotation

Here is my interceptor

```
@Aspect
public class MyInterceptor {
    @Around("execution(* com.test.example..*(..))")
    public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object result;
        try {
            result = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and here is my annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String reason();
}
```

and here is the class

```
@MyAnnotation(reason="yes")
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
}
```

In interceptor I need to get the annotation and the value assigned to reason attribute.

Comment: You need to define a pointcut using "within" for your exemple @Pointcut("within(@MyAnnotation *)") that means all type with @MyAnnotation

Answer (score 2):

Interceptor class to get value of the annotation marked at class level

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyInterceptor {
    @Around("@target(annotation)")
    public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(" called with '" + annotation.reason() + "'");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```